# How is $\int\cos\left((\omega_1-\omega_2)t-\phi\right)\;dt + \int\cos\left((\omega_1+\omega_2)t+\phi\right)\;dt $ equal to zero?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have this integral of two cosines with different frequencies, $\omega_1 \neq \omega_2$, which are integrated from zero to one common period. The problem is that I can't figure out how to solve it, because it should be equal to zero at the end.

$$\int\cos\left((\omega_1-\omega_2)t-\phi\right)\;dt + \int\cos\left((\omega_1+\omega_2)t+\phi\right)\;dt $$

[image: original image]

Comment: It should be $0$ without any bounds?

Comment: He said from zero to one common period. So I think that is meant to give us the bounds. This seems like an orthogonality integral.

Answer (score 0):

What I think of this problem is there are two waveforms which are some combination of 2 simpler waveforms with frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ giving rise to 2 other waveforms of frequencies $\omega1-\omega2$ and $\omega1+\omega2$ with but with the same phases $\phi$.

Anyway coming to the problem in hand, let us consider the two waveforms separately:
$x_1(t)=\cos[(\omega_1-\omega_2)t -\phi]$ and $x_2(t)=\cos[(\omega_1+\omega_2)t+\phi]$

Both of these waveforms are periodic but they will be having different frequencies and hence different time periods.

$T_1=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1-\omega_2}$ and $T_2=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_1+\omega_2}$

Now if you integrate the first waveform from $0$ to $T_1$ and the second waveform from $0$ to $T_2$ you will get both the integrals as $0$.
Another insight is maybe the common period means the overall period of the sum of the two waveforms which is nothing but the LCM of $T_1$ and $T_2$ finding the common period will involve analysing different cases of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.

Hope this helps...